# Yii2:Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model          = new Bookings();
        $temp           = new RoomTypes();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $roomtype = $model->room_type;
            $totalremain = RoomTypes::find('total_remain')->where(['room_type' => $model->room_type])->one();
            if ($roomtype->$totalremain > 0) 
            {
                    $imageName   = $model->first_name;
                    $mobile      = $model->primary_mobile;
                    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/id_images/' . $imageName . '_' . $mobile . '.' . $model->file->extension);
                    //save the path in the db column
                    $model->id_image = 'uploads/id_images/' . $imageName . '_' . $mobile . '.' . $model->file->extension;
                    $model->save();   
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "This room Types are full ";
                }
        }

        else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'temp'  => $temp,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I need to check `total_remain` from Roomtypes model is > 0 from `room_types` in Bookings model, before submitting the form if user submit the form it should get flash meassage saying "this room are full"
Getting this error, how to solve this

getting error at  `if ($roomtype->$totalremain > 0)`

Room types model

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;


/**
 * This is the model class for table "room_types".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $room_id
 * @property string $room_type
 * @property integer $total_count
 * @property string $description
 * @property integer $extra_beds
 * @property string $images
 * @property string $status
 * @property integer $rate
 * @property integer $adults_count
 * @property integer $child_count
 * @property integer $total_people
 */
class RoomTypes extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public $imageFiles;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'room_types';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['room_id','total_booked','total_remain','total_count', 'extra_beds', 'rate', 'adults_count', 'child_count'], 'integer'],
            [['status'], 'string'],
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4,'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'on' => 'update-photo-upload'],
            [['room_type'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['description'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
            [['images'], 'string', 'max' => 500]
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'room_id' => 'Room Number',
            'room_type' => 'Room Type',
            'total_count' => 'Total Count',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'extra_beds' => 'Extra Beds',
            //'images' => 'Images',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'rate' => 'Rate',
            'adults_count' => 'Adults Count',
            'child_count' => 'Child Count',
            'total_remain' =>'Remaing Rooms',
            'total_booked' => 'Total Rooms Booked',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is $roomtype an object?.The code $roomtype->$totalremain itself is not meaningful.If $roomtype is an object then it should be like $roomtype->totalremain.May be the condition should be rewritten like if ($totalremain->totalremain > 0)

Comment: if ($totalremain->totalremain > 0) is giving error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `$roomtype` is the room_type from model which will be select by user in form from dropdown

Comment: $totalremain->total_remain.Check in RoomTypes model class how total_remain attribute is written

Comment: Or just show me the RoomTypes model

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109389/discussion-between-kiran-muralee-and-saurabh).

Comment: $totalremain = RoomTypes::find('total_remain')->where(['room_type' => $model->room_type])->one(); I have not find a property total_remain in RoomTypes model

Comment: [['room_id','total_booked','total_remain','total_count', 'extra_beds', 'rate', 'adults_count', 'child_count'], 'integer'],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code if ($roomtype->$totalremain > 0) is causing the problem.Change it like if ($totalremain->total_remain > 0)